# inspect.getmodule discrepancy for datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7

For classes defined in python code, inspect.getmodule works for both objects and types

```
>>> import calendar
>>> c = calendar.Calendar()
>>> print inspect.getmodule(c)
<module 'calendar' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.pyc'>
>>> print inspect.getmodule(type(c))
<module 'calendar' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.pyc'>
```

But in case of datetime, it doesn't work for objects:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print inspect.getmodule(d)
None
>>> print inspect.getmodule(type(d))
<module 'datetime' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so'>
```

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: Calendar() creates an object and now() just returns the time?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that:  

    `>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()  
    >>> repr(d)  
    'datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 3, 19, 8, 48, 279667)'  
    >>> print type(d)  
    <type 'datetime.datetime'>`

Comment: the only difference i can see is that datetime is compiled into a dynamic .so lib and calendar is kept as .pyc

Answer (score 0):

The `calendar` module is pure python, whereas the `datetime` module is an extension.

According to the docs, [`inspect.getmodule()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) is intended for retrieving information about source code, so it's obviously limited in what it can do with objects created by extension modules.